# What is the best sql data type for x.x.x

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datatypes

What is the best data type for field with format like this X.X.X.x

Here is the sample field data

```
15.8.0
15.8.1
15.8.2
15.8.3
15.8.4
1.8.0
2.8.2
9.8.2
9.8.3
9.8.4
10.8.0
13.15.0.1
13.15.1.1
13.15.2.1
13.15.3.1
13.15.4.1
13.0.0
26.0.0.1
26.0.0.2
```

This field use as primary field of table

Thanks

Comment: 4 separate (TINYINT) columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say it would be the best ("best" in what sense?) but one way to do this is to have the 4 numbers in 4 separate `TINYINT` columns.

You can have the `PRIMARY KEY` as a composite 4-column one or as a persisted column. Considering from the data provided that the 4th number can be `NULL`, I'd choose the persisted as primary key and add a unique constraints on the 4 columns:

```
create table versions
( a tinyint not null,
  b tinyint not null,
  c tinyint not null,
  d tinyint null,
  version as cast( concat( a, '.', b, '.', c, 
                           case when d is null then '' else concat('.',  d) end
                   ) as varchar(15)) 
      persisted,
  constraint version_uq
      unique clustered (a,b,c,d),
  constraint versions_pk
      primary key (version),
) ;
```

Tested at [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/BMNP4236).

---

Another option would be to use the [`HierarchyID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx) type.